# Algorithm to shuffle a list to minimise equal neighbours

Tags: python, algorithm, shuffle

I want to shuffle a list like this one:-

```
to_shuffle = [ a, b, b, b, b, a, c, b, a, b ]
```

to minimise the number of repeating elements.  Initially, I
thought about popping elements off the top of `to_shuffle` and either
pushing them onto a another list `shuffled` if the element is
different from the previously pushed element, or else push it on to
the bottom of `to_shuffle` and try another element.  This would result
in:-

```
shuffled = [ a, b, a, c, b, a, b, b, b, b ]
```

which, in this example, isn't any better - there's still 4 b in a row (although this method *sometimes* reduces repeating elements).

What I then thought was to start by making a bucket for each class of
element:-

```
buckets = [ (a, [a, a, a]), (b, [b, b, b, b, b, b]), (c, [c]) ]
```

sort the buckets by size, descending

```
buckets = [ (b, [b, b, b, b, b, b]), (a, [a, a, a]), (c, [c]) ]
```

keeping track of the last element shuffled

```
last = None
```

cycle through the buckets, starting with the biggest, and pop off an
element if not equal to `last`, resort the buckets and do it again:-

```
sorted = [ b ]

buckets = [ (b, [b, b, b, b, b]), (a, [a, a, a]), (c, [c]) ] 
last = b

sorted = [ b, a ]

buckets = [ (b, [b, b, b, b, b]), (a, [a, a]), (c, [c]) ] 
last = a

sorted = [ b, a, b ]

buckets = [ (b, [b, b, b, b]), (a, [a, a]), (c, [c]) ] 
last = b

sorted = [ b, a, b, a ]

buckets = [ (b, [b, b, b, b]), (a, [a]), (c, [c]) ] 
.
.
.
sorted = [ b, a, b, a, b, a, b, c, b, b ]
```

which is a much better result.

**Is there a name for this algorithm and if so is there a python (2.7) implementation of it?**

Here's some rather shoddy code:-

```
test = [ 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b' ]
expected = [ 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b' ]

def sort_buckets(buckets):
    return sorted(buckets, key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)

def make_buckets(to_shuffle):
    h = {}
    buckets = []
    for e in to_shuffle:
        if e not in h:
            h[e] = []
        h[e].append(e)
    for k, elems in h.iteritems():
        buckets.append((k, elems))
    return buckets

def shuffle(to_shuffle):
    buckets = make_buckets(to_shuffle)
    shuffled = []
    last = ''
    while len(buckets) > 1:
        buckets = sort_buckets(buckets)
        for i in range(len(buckets)):
            candidate = buckets[i][0]
            if candidate == last:
                continue
            t = buckets.pop(i)
            last = candidate
            shuffled.append(t[1][-1])
            if len(t[1]) > 1:
                buckets.append((t[0], t[1][:-1]))
            break
    t = buckets.pop()
    shuffled += t[1]
    return shuffled

print expected
print shuffle(test)
```

Comment: Is randomness part of the requirement? What you're trying to achieve isn't really shuffling, but rather avoiding consecutive occurrences of the same character...

Comment: No, as you say, avoiding consecutive occurrences of the same character is the goal, not randomness. Is it not shuffling? What would you call it?

Comment: I'd call it "repeat-free rearrangement"... When you "shuffle" a deck of cards, do you expect randomness, or do you go through the cards to make sure the cards are in the order you want?

Answer (score 3):

Sort them in order of frequency, then put them into a new array at alternating positions, first working from left to right then from right to left.

So in the example you gave, sorted is `{b,b,b,b,b,b,a,a,a,c}`, then the "every other place" operation takes it to    `{b,_,b,_,b,_,b,_,b,_}`, then we continue to fill in the blanks from the right (or from the left if that results in fewer identical adjacents): `{b,c,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,b}`. There's only one identical adjacent pair in that answer. That ensures that the most frequent item shows up at the beginning (and possibly end) of the list where it can't be beside itself on one side, at least. Then you'll only have identical items beside each other if more than half are of one type.

Here's a case where you would want to fill in the second pass starting at the left: `{a,a,b,b,c,c}` => `{a,_,a,_,b,_}`, now if we fill in from the right we'll get a double b so we start again from the left: `{a,b,a,c,b,c}`.

Comment: Does this algorithm have a name? It doesn't answer the question, but it certainly is beautiful; thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that restarting from the left to fill the even positions is always at least as good, and sometimes better than, "folding back" from the right.  With restart-from-left, the only case where you will get adjacent equal pairs is if there's an element with frequency > RoundUp(n/2) (i.e. a strict majority), and then you get the minimum possible (i.e. unavoidable) number of them, because any element with lower frequency is incapable of wrapping around far enough to "touch its tail".  With fold-back-from-right, you can get a lot more.

Comment: In the first example I gave, starting over from the left gives two adjacent identical pairs, but starting from the left gives only one. That does appear to be the only type of example, though. Maybe if I started `{_,b,_,b,_,b,_,b,_,b}` a case could be made for always starting from the left, but if there were an odd total number of elements that strategy might not work out perfectly either.

Comment: @jah good question about what it is called. I don't know. However there are similar permutations used in card magic called in-shuffles and out-shuffles. Persi Diaconis and Ron Graham treat the subject in their book.

Comment: Oh, and the permutation where I start from the left and do the second half from the right is called a "milk shuffle", I think.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is pretty easy to understand, and I believe it is correct. It can be made a little easier to read using Python's built-in `Counter` collection.

```
from collections import Counter

def careful_shuffle(lst):
    '''Returns a new list based on a given iterable, with the elements shuffled
    such that the number of duplicate consecutive elements are minimized.'''

    c = Counter(lst)
    if len(c) < 2:
        # Return early if it's trivial.
        return lst

    output = []
    last = None
    while True:
        # All we need are the current 2 most commonly occurring items. This
        # works even if there's only 1 or even 0 items left, because the
        # Counter object will still return the requested number of results,
        # with count == 0.
        common_items = c.most_common(2)
        avail_items = [key for key, count in common_items if count]

        if not avail_items:
            # No more items to process.
            break

        # Just reverse the list if we just saw the first item. This simplies
        # the logic in case we actually only have 1 type of item left (in which
        # case we have no choice but to choose it).
        if avail_items[0] == last:
            avail_items.reverse()

        # We've found the next item. Add it to the output and update the
        # counter.
        next_item = avail_items[0]
        output.append(next_item)
        c[next_item] -= 1
        last = next_item

    return output
```

Comment: Thank you, this indeed makes it clearer. Your implementation does produce the expected sequence of elements, whereas the final `a` and the `c` elements were interchanged in mine. Does it have a name though?

Comment: @jah: Unfortunately, not one that I know of.